# How did they build Jurassic World on Isla Nublar?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

At the end of Jurassic Park John Hammond's experiment in building a dinosaur zoo had drastically failed. Dinosaurs were out of their paddocks, they were breeding, [Velociraptors may or may not have been getting off the island](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/in-the-book-jurassic-park-does-the-lysine-contingency-actually-get-explained).

Oh, and there was the matter of their prime exhibit wrecking the main vistor's centre.

[image]

Over the 20 years since the failure of Jurassic Park, and the opening of Jurassic World, the dinosaurs surely developed some sort of wild ecosystem. But, it looks as if the Park has been functional for at least a few years, as they are talking about attendance rates over time.

When, and more importantly *how* did they regain control of Isla Nublar?

Comment: The issue of the main visitors center was pretty much explained in JW: board it up and ignore it.

Comment: Yeah, but who boarded it up? What happened to the original dinosaurs? Granted there was no more goats, but the T-rex all of a sudden had an all you can eat dino-buffet.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr No idea about jurassic-world, but in the jurassic-park novel ended with the army bombing the shit of of the dinos.

Comment: How did they build Jurassic World? _Not carefully enough._

Comment: Obviously, they spared no expense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Based on *Jurassic Park*

As has been mentioned, it's likely that most of the original JP dinosaurs simply died.  There are numerous ways this could have happened:

- Natural predation by larger dinosaurs
- The Lysine Contingency (explained as mitigated by lysine-rich food sources, but those may have been depleted over time)
- Predator overpopulation, leading to a collapse of the food chain
- Human action (such as the bombings described in the books)

It's also worth noting that the fact that "life found a way" to let the dinosaurs breed in the wild (with some female specimens changing to become male), there's no guarantee that that happened in sufficient quantities to create a viable population.  Many species may have died off immediately, because they couldn't generate enough males or because they were eaten before their populations could reach a viable size.

### Based on *Jurassic World*

However, it is also clear that the Jurassic World park has a much more potent, militarized infrastructure than the original Jurassic Park did.  My personal expectation is that Day 1 of JW's construction featured a heavily-armed private military force landing on the island and re-capturing the surviving animals.

For example, it's been pointed out that the T-Rex has scars matching those of the one from the original park.  A dinosaur outbreak can be chaos when it's unexpected and there are civilians in danger, but they are *just animals* after all.  A well-coordinated, well-prepared force wouldn't have too much trouble tranquilizing the animals they could, and killing the ones they couldn't.  Hell, a simple gas release from the air would probably be quite effective in pacifying or killing the native life, without any danger to the humans involved.  From there they could sweep in, secure the animals in portable enclosures, and begin construction.

This is never specifically described, that I can recall, but it fits perfectly with the greater militarization and improved infrastructure highlighted so strongly in the new film. For example, when the Indominus Rex first escaped (before they realized how dangerous it was), they rapidly initiated pre-established protocols for dinosaur recapture, and mobilized well-equipped teams to bring it in.  It's likely that these protocols were used, or even developed, during the re-taking of the island.

Comment: Knew I read it somewhere... [the director confirmed that it's the same t-rex](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Jurassic-World-Confirms-Appearance-By-One-Badass-Jurassic-Park-Star-71157.html)

Comment: Awesome link, that made the story cooler

Comment: The work started long before that landing. The InGen teams in JP3 had some specialized capture and containment gear, and a working playbook.

Answer (score 0):

From some of the scenes in Jurassic World (Getting the jeep to work scene) you can infer that some areas were just abandoned and not boarded up.  You can assume that from experience with Site B that Ingen learned how to cope with the ecosystem.  By the way, there is no evidence that this wild ecosystem is viable.  For example when the Tyrannosaurus finally ate the last big dino, then what? There is nothing else on that island to feed on so the large animals will quickly die. This includes the breeding velociraptors.  That is, as long as they never learned to swim the shark infested coast of Costa Rica.
As for the small animals, there is no way of knowing, a quick dose of poison may destroy them.
As someone mentioned in the comments, in the book the Costa Rican Army bombed the dinosaurs and with the help of Grant, located all the underground raptor nests.  However the book paints a more bleak ending where the Compy's have gotten to the mainland and have begun to be part of the local ecosystem by eating small mammals including human babies but even in the book, no large dinos got off the island (Close call with some Velociraptors but that was the whole point of the book).  In the end, life did not find a way.

Comment: The t-rex in JW has scars that match up with the scars the t-rex would have sustained in JP, the implication being that it's the same one. And since other dinosaurs, not just raptors were likely able to breed due to the dna, there's plenty of possibility that life *did* find a way.

Comment: You may be right, I did not see the scars before the Trex battle with indomitable.  I assumed the scars were from the fight.  I further assumed the TRex was either new or from site B.  I think the book and the movie both stated that the DNA of the Dinos was modified to grow fast to adulthood.

Answer (score 0):

Jurassic Park was never finished completion; the tour they offered to Grant and his constituents were meant to reassure and solicit it's potential. Whole sections of the island that were of the original park are derelict and left unattened. Jurassic world was built on the infrastructure they were gonna lay out before the incident.

Answer (score 0):

In the film, Rexy was the only Dinosaur that survived on Isla Nublar, but when Masani Corp bought Ingen, they began creating more dinosaurs. Rexy was re-captured, and some were transported from Isla Sorna. When they built Jurassic World, they needed to capture any surviving dinosaurs.

Comment: What's the source for all this?