# How did the dinosaurs in the Jurassic Park movie sequels survive without lysine?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

In *[Jurassic Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park_(film))*, we're told that the dinosaurs are built with a failsafe.

> **ARNOLD:** *The lysine contingency is intended to prevent the spread
> of the animals in case they ever got off the  island.  Dr. Wu inserted a gene that makes a single faulty enzyme in protein metabolism. The animals can't manufacture the amino acid lysine.  Unless they're continually supplied with lysine by us, they slip into a coma and die.*

Which is all fine and good-- unless you then make [<s>three</s> five sequels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park) filled with dinosaurs, none of which are being provided lysine. The first two sequels take place on an island that's been completely abandoned by In-Gen. Jurassic World features the original T-Rex, even though it should have died after the first Jurassic Park was abandoned.

Did they ever address this address this in the sequels?

Comment: In the second one, didnt they say something about them seeking out food that had lysine in it? Im not certain, but I feel I've heard that.

Comment: "life finds a way"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the *Masrani* website created for the promotion of *Jurassic World*, there is a ["computer terminal"](http://www.masraniglobal.com/terminal/system/desktop.html) one can use. After typing `READ` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> `05121994` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the following is displayed:

> [image: A list of logs on a computer terminal, one read, transcribed below.]
>
> ---BEGIN LOG---
>
> OWNER: WU, HENRY
> DATE: 05/12/1994 1215 CST
> SUBJECT: LYSINE
> NOTES: THERE MUST BE A HICCUP IN THE LYSINE CONTINGENCY SOMEWHERE. THE ANIMALS HAVE NOT PERISHED. WHAT'S MORE ASTONISHING IS THAT THEY'RE BREEDING. I'VE SEEN THE NESTS MYSELF. ONE CAN ONLY ASSUME INCLUSIONS FROM HYPEROLIUS VIRIDIFLAVUS WERE TO BLAME. COMPLETELY UNPRECEDENTED IN MY FIELD OF RESEARCH. LIFE FOUND A WAY?
>
> ---END LOG---

It is a log message by Henry Wu, dated 12 May 1994, noting that the lysine contingency has failed and that they're breeding. He assumes that inclusions from Hyperolius viridiflavus (common reed frog) were to blame, without specifying to blame for *what*, so the message can be read as either, or both.

Comment: A great find. This log entry was written after the events of *Jurassic Park*

Comment: A bit of a weak answer, I must admit, since he may have meant only the latter part. But an interesting website nonetheless. I've read an explanation of how they cloned an aquatic animal (not many mosquitos under water) and for the lack of feathers (again, frog DNA).

Comment: Don't sell it short. The fact that Wu acknowledges that it worked, but then suddenly didn't (due to precisely the same issues they had with the '*fertility contingency*') is a really solid explanation.

Comment: @Valorum also see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/279217/19561

Answer (score 4):

So my comment was right. Based on http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Lysine_contingency

It says that the dinosaurs ate foods that were rich in Lysine, like soya beans or chickens, while the carnivores simply ate the herbivores.

Also, after some Googling, I found [In the book "Jurassic Park" does the Lysine Contingency actually get explained?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/in-the-book-jurassic-park-does-the-lysine-contingency-actually-get-explained) which the answer explains where in the **book** it is found. Just in case you wanted to know that as well.

Comment: Chickens are made of meat, right? Why would the herbivores eat chickens? Why wouldn't the carnivores eat chickens?

Comment: Chickens definitely aren't part of the herbivore diet?

Comment: Oh my. I was typing from my phone lol. Edited to reflect that herbivores do not, in fact, eat chickens.

Comment: Life finds a way.

Comment: This answer appears to address the book sequels, not the movie sequels.

Comment: There are some deer on an island that specifically bite off the legs of chicks to get some needed nutrition.  Herbivores can absolutely supplement their diet with meat.